# Convert HTML Code to Image at Server Side

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I want to convert html code to image on run of PHP code through CLI

```
<div id="canvas" style="background-color: white;">  
    <table width="340px" style="340px;" >
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="header.jpeg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="">
            Dear , sss<br>
            Sincerely,<br>
            ameeth </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="footer.jpeg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried `html2canvas`, it works on browser mode, but I need to run this as cron.  Can someone show how to be executed through CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use mPDF or tcpdf.
If you want to save a page in pdf using mpdf, get the html code, then:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/tools/mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}/{nb}');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');

file_put_contents( 'filename'.pdf' , $content);
```